# gatling/Scala: Write custom feeder (read csv from url) - random iterator?

Tags: scala, csv, random, iterator, gatling

I am new to scala  and I am trying to write a custom feeder for gatling that reads a csv file from a url (similar jsonUrl-Feeder).

I am unsure about how to do this. I tried the following, but now I need to implement additional methods:

```
package common

import scala.io.Source
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

class CsvURLFeeder(url: String) extends Map[String, String] {

 val source = Source.fromURL(url)
 val reader = source.bufferedReader()

 val attributeName = reader.readLine()

 var list : ListBuffer[Map[String, String]] = new ListBuffer[Map[String, String]]() 

 val input = Stream.continually(reader readLine)


 for( line <- input){
   list += Map(attributeName-> line) 
 }

 def getFeeder() : Iterator[Map[String, String]]  = {
   return list.iterator
 }

}
```

missing methods:

```
// Members declared in scala.collection.immutable.Map
def +[B1 >: String](kv: (String, B1)): scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,B1] = ???

// Members declared in scala.collection.MapLike
def -(key: String): scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = ???
def get(key: String): Option[String] = ???
1def iterator: Iterator[(String, String)] = ???
```

Also, I have no idea how to make the iterator random. I don't want to go through the list one by one.

Isn't there a similar feeder who does the same stuff for me?
Or what would be the best way to implement such a feeder?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Took away the part "extends Map[String, String]" because it is obviously not doing anything. Now - of course - I don't need to implement those methods any more.

Now I can see that something is wrong with the for-loop... it never stops printing "null". Also, the first line is wrong. It is "Stream("actual first line",?)".

**UPDATE 2**
I changed the reading part to

```
var list : ListBuffer[Map[String, String]] = new ListBuffer[Map[String, String]]() 

var line = "";
while ( {line = reader.readLine ; line != null} ){
  list += Map(attributeName-> line) 
}
```

... and this works now!! Cool.

But it looks pretty ugly. Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: @faizan Thanks for correcting my English. :)

Comment: Why is your class extending a Map??

Comment: Do you want to model your csv reader as lazy Stream or lazy Iterable ?

Comment: A gatling feeder must be an Iterator[Map[String, T]] , that's why.

Comment: I am talking about `extends Map[String, String]` part in `class CsvURLFeeder(url: String) extends Map[String, String]`

Comment: You're right.... it's not necessary!

Comment: Now I find that reading the file does not work correctly .... The first line of the loop is "Stream("first line", ?)," and after the last line I get endlessly "null".